# How to replace character from array items using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have got an array items dynamically like this **["{text: "US"}", "{text: "Mexico"}", "{text: "Brazil"}"]**. I need to replace this char **"{** to this char **{** and  this char **}"** this char **}**. After replacing finally I need output like this **[{text: "US"}, {text: "Mexico"}, {text: "Brazil"}]**. If it single object means I can replace. but for array list not getting. I have tried as below, this one is not working   How can achieve this one?

```
dynamicSubRegions =["{text: "US"}", "{text: "Mexico"}", "{text: "Brazil"}"];
var dynamicSubRegionsFinal = dynamicSubRegions[dynamicSubRegions.indexOf('"{')] = '{';
```

Comment: It's very hard to tell what the array actually looks like because of the syntax errors. Do you have an array that has one string element or one that has three strings/objects?

Comment: y are you quoting object as string ?**[{text: "US"}, {text: "Mexico"}, {text: "Brazil"}];**

Comment: Can it be that `dynamicSubRegions` contains a json response that you only need to decode instead of manually search/replacing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your array syntax is wrong and the double quotes arn't inside the variable

```
dynamicSubRegions =["{text: \"US\"}", "{text: \"Mexico\"}", "{text: \"Brazil\"}"];
alert(dynamicSubRegions[0]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dftgY/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, you are trying to convert the `string` values to `json` object.

There is a problem with the format of the json key, it has to be wrapped in `""` for it to be valid input for the [JSON.parse(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method, which can convert a string to a valid json object.

```
var array = ["{text: \"US\"}", "{text: \"Mexico\"}", "{text: \"Brazil\"}"];

array.forEach(function(value, key){
    array[key] = JSON.parse(value.replace('{text:', '{"text":'));
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XtAGd/2/)